# Can't load Data in Html element with Jquery Load method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am making ASP.NET MVC application and I want to load data in the html element without reloading the whole page. But it doesn't work. I watched all the videos and read all the tutorials, but can't find what is the mistake in my code.

At the end of my Index page I have the following code:

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#2a").click(function () {
        $("#div1").load('T.txt');
    });
});
</script>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button id="2a">this is button</button>
```

This is corresponding image:

[image]

this is my T.txt file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `T.txt` is in `yourProject/Views/Home`. ASP.NET MVC can't serve files located there.
You need to move `T.txt` to `yourProject/Content` and then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#2a").click(function () {
        $("#div1").load('/Content/T.txt');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this works.

```
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button onclick="loadDoc()">this is button</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "T.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just replace that with T.txt